How to remove Wireframe during Cycles render?
why is this model showing a wireframe even in cycles rendered preview?
heres the file in case needed
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DOIKHTSoA0De0PBzRo4Gy6nloEmRv_Tc/view?usp=sharing


In the shared file I don't see the wireframe, maybe check if the Wireframe option is activated in the Viewport Overlays panel?

As @moonboots says, check for the Wireframe overlays... the rendered preview may be rendered as the name says, but it is still just a preview and it shows overlays if they are enabled (like the grid in the background as well), only when you actually render the image the overlays are gone without disabling them.

@moonboots I've downloaded the shared file and I see the wireframe and Wireframe is enabled in Overlays.

Thank you so much brothers!

You have Wireframe enabled in the Overlays for the viewport. Disable it and the wireframe will not show. This overlay works in all shading modes, even in the Rendered preview.

